# Determine whether $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} e^{\frac{-1}{(x^{2} + y^{2})}}$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Determine whether $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} e^{\frac{-1}{(x^{2} + y^{2})}}$$

exists.

Claim: The limit does exist.

Justification:  This is where I'm having problems. I know in one variable calculus that $$\lim_{t \to 0}e^{\frac{-1}{t^{2}}} = 0$$

The first thing I tried was building a composition of previously defined limits. In particular I tried using $f(x,y) = x + y$ and $g(t) = e^{\frac{-1}{t^{2}}}$. With this idea I was hoping to be able to compare $(x+y)^{2} = x^{2} + 2xy + y^{2}$ to $x^{2} + y^{2}$ and get something I could then use the squeeze principle on. But after manipulation I end up with

$$ e^{\frac{-1}{x^{2} + y^{2}}} \leq e^{\frac{-1}{x^{2} + 2xy + y^{2}}}$$

Which doesn't give me much.

The only other idea that comes to mind is to "try" and find a satisfactory $\delta$, but that looks like it will be hell. I must be missing a comparison to apply to this. Could I get some assistance?

EDIT: Ooooh...I just noticed polar coordinates will make it alot easier to solve. But I want to leave the question here. Assuming I didn't "know" about the polar coordinates approach what may work?

Comment: Can you use polar coordinates ?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah, I just looked over things and noticed that right before you typed...Yes. out of curiosity how could I approach it if I didin't have polar coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it without polar coordinates, one way is to leverage the fact $$e^p \geq 1 + p$$ for $p \geq 0$ to conclude that $$0 \leq e^{-p} \leq \frac{1}{1 + p}$$ for $p > 0$ also. Now substitute $p = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$ and (after simplifying) notice that the denominator is always strictly positive, so the simplified expression is continuous on all of $\Bbb{R}^2$. You can then use a two-variable version of Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: So a truncated Taylor expansion was necessary then?...Interesting...and nice.

Comment: Not strictly necessary, but certainly sufficient. Ultimately it's somewhat a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Use that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}}e^{-1/t}=0.
\end{align*}
Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $0<t<\delta$ implies that $e^{-1/t}=|e^{-1/t}|<\epsilon$.

For any $(x,y)$ with $0<|(x,y)|<\sqrt{\delta}$, then $0<\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<\sqrt{\delta}$, so $0<x^{2}+y^{2}<\delta$ and hence $e^{-1/(x^{2}+y^{2})}<\epsilon$, done.

Comment: what about approaching from the left side?

Comment: The limit is then infinity.

Comment: I agree. But wouldn't that be a possibility if I'm approaching from different directions?

Comment: You just pick up the useful limit for your context. Note that $x^{2}+y^{2}>0$, so plugging this corresponds to the right one, not the left one.

Comment: I'm actually trying to work out how you got $\delta = \sqrt{\delta}$ in the one dimensional case. I was attempting to rework it and I can't seem to get the result. The inequality underneath makes sense to me, it is just establishing the other fact above.